# Getting Promise data in the response in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one service like below

**getServices.js**

```
angular
    .module('adminsuite')
    .service('getAllSurveyService', getAllSurveyService);
    getAllSurveyService.$inject = ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout', '$q'];
     function getAllSurveyService($http,$cookieStore,$rootScope,$timeout,$q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var session = $cookieStore.get('globals');
        var data = {
            sessionId : session.currentUser.session
        }
        var surveyData = {
            'Data' : JSON.stringify(data)
        }
        var requestData = JSON.stringify(surveyData)
        //console.log(requestData);

        this.surveyList = function () {
            //return session;
            return $http.post('http://apidev.1pt.mobi/V3.0/api/Survey/Surveys',  requestData, {headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}})
            .then(function(response){
                        var sendData = deferred.resolve(response.data);
                        //console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                        return response.data;
                    }, function(error){
                        return error;
                    });
        }

    };
```

Below controller i am using for fetching the data

**controller.js**

```
angular.module("adminsuite").controller("surveyController",['getAllSurveyService', '$scope', function(getAllSurveyService, $scope){
    $scope.header = "Header";
    $scope.allSurveys = getAllSurveyService.surveyList();
    console.log($scope.allSurveys);
    //console.log($scope.getSession);
 }]);
```

In the console am getting the response like this
[image: Image for console data reference]

After this am trying to get data inside the promise object but am unable to fetch that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getAllSurveyService.surveyList()` return a promise, so you need to get the data like this (In your controller):

```
getAllSurveyService.surveyList().then(
    function( data ) {
        $scope.allSurveys = data;
        console.log($scope.allSurveys);
    }
);
```